# Request Headers is not woking on Visual Studio Dev Tunnel

Tags: visual-studio

In my Blazor WASM, I am filling the headers with the name initial_key that needs to retrieved on my API Controller. This is how I fill the headers

```
private async Task<T> SendRequest<T>(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    request.Headers.Add("initial_key", _requestHeaderValue);
}
```

In the .net core API, I try to get the this header like so:

```
if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("initial_key", out var loginKey)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loginKey));
```

In my DevTools, I can see the the value

[image]

Why can't I populate my `loginKey` in the API?

When I run the project with and without debugging (I do not use the dev tunnels), I do not get any issues. The error happens when I run the project using the dev tunnel.

The specific error I get is

> "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'loginKey')"

Answer (score 0):

For those who will encounter this issue.

For some reason when using the dev tunnel, the key `initial_key` is not accepted. I just changed the `initial_key` to `initialKey` and the error is gone.